# How do I create a nice message when there are no rows in a Microsoft rdlc sub report?

Tags: report, reporting, reportviewer, subreport, report-viewer2010

I am using the ReportViewer control in a website, my reports contain 3 or more sub reports. Often the data in the sub-report does not exist due to it being optional data. I need to output a nicely formatted and aligned message to let the reader know. I have the following code:

```
    protected void ReportViewer1_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtReport = GetReportSub(reportId);
        foreach (DataRow drRow in dtReport.Rows)
        {
            if (Replace(drRow["subName"].ToString(), " ", "") == e.ReportPath)
            {
                string sSQLMain = SQLReplacer(drRow["subSQL"].ToString());
                DataTable dtData = BuildCollectionArray(sSQLMain, new OdbcParameter());
                if (dtData.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    //TODO: Hide the report and show a friendly message
                }
                else
                {
                    ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DS" + Replace(drRow["subName"].ToString(), " ", ""), dtData);
                    e.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which will fetch the data and add it to the report that requires it. However, if there is no data the only option is the NoRowsMessage property. However the NoRowsMessage property in the main report on each of the sub reports is too limiting.

Ideally I'd like to have each sub-report take care of the no rows message itself using an exporession or code. However the flaw in the Microsoft way of working appears to be that the report is conditional on there being data to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a workable solution to my problem. I am ignoring the default no rows functions and instead doing the work in the sub report.

I have a Tablix with my details in, I will then create an extra Textbox with my no rows message. The no rows message is hidden depending on the DataSet such as:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!ActID.Value, "DSSub") > 0, true, false)
```